# How can I detect two distinct touches

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way to detect just 2 distinct touches? I just want to track the touches for my two buttons, which is a sprite, but whenever I have another touch other than my first two touches, it affects my touch with my button. Is there a way to get rid of that third touch?
I wish you could help me with this problem.Thank You!

Comment: I think showing the code will help.

Comment: See my [answer to this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595298/get-the-sender-touch-for-cctouchesmovednsset-touches-witheventuievent-eve/7608574#7608574

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

1. Create an int activeTouches
2. On touches began, increment that activeTouches counter by the amount
3. On touches ended, decrement that activeTouches counter by the amount
4. Before doing anything check if activeTouches <= the max number of touches you need