# Get the sender touch for ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

How can i find in a multi touch cocos2d app what was the touch that called `ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` ? I can get all the touches using `[event allTouches]` but how can i find which touch called the function, for example when i would like for that specific touch to display a specific NSLog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The touch events provide you with a UITouch* object for each finger. The UITouch* remains the same throughout the whole touch, from began to ended/cancelled. You can retain the UITouch* in the began event and release it (and set it to nil) in the ended and cancelled events.

Btw, the input class KKInput ([class reference](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/Kobold2D/html/interface_k_k_input.html)) of [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) (improved Cocos2D makes that a whole lot easier. Starting with Preview 5 you can just get the list of current touches at any time, in any class or method because KKInput keeps track of the touches for you.